# Choosing non-adjacent chairs

Tags: combinatorics

1. There are $n$ chairs in a row. Find the number of ways of
   choosing $k$ of these chairs, so that no two chosen chairs are
   adjacent.
2. There are 10 chairs in a circle, labelled from 1 to 10. Find the
   number of ways of choosing 3 of these chairs, so that no two chosen
   chairs are adjacent.
3. There are $n$ chairs in a circle, labelled from 1 to $n.$ Find
   the number of ways of choosing $k$ of these chairs, so that no two
   chosen chairs are adjacent.

I'm fairly new to the concept of distributions and I'm confused about how you would go about solving these problems, even though I'm pretty sure they're connected.

Comment: For the first question, are you familiar with the [gap method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477137/using-gap-method-while-selecting)?

Comment: **Please do not discuss this problem!** This is an active homework problem. @Rose Callihan: I realize that homework may be challenging. If you wish to receive some help from the staff or other students, I encourage you to use the resources that the online classes provide, such as the Message Board. Thanks.

Comment: @wonderman this is not an active homework problem. I have a math exercise book that I have been working on to improve my skills and this problem came from it.

Comment: @Rose Callihan: All of the problems you have posted are from the same online class.

Comment: @wonderman I honestly don't know what you are talking about and I am tired of arguing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct in thinking that the questions are connected. They all depend upon the method used in part (a).

(a) The chosen chairs occupy $k$ of the $n-k+1$ positions between and at the ends of the row of non-chosen chairs. The number of choices is therefore $$\begin{pmatrix}n-k+1\\k\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

(b) If chair 1 is **not** chosen, then the choice of $3$ chairs from the remaining $9$ is calculated as in (a). If chair 1  **is** chosen then, ignoring chair $1$ and the  chairs adjacent to $1$, the choice of $2$ chairs from $7$ is also calculated as in part (a).

The number of choices is therefore $$\begin{pmatrix}7\\3\\\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}6\\2\\\end{pmatrix}=50.$$

(c) As in part (b) we have two cases:

a)If chair $1$ chosen

b)If Chair $1$ isn’t chosen

Combine the number of cases, we get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}n-k\\k\\\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}n-k-1\\k-1\\\end{pmatrix}=\frac{n(n-k-1)!}{k!(n-2k)!}.$$