# Arrangements around a table without choosing neighbours

Tags: combinatorics

Twelve knights are arranged around King’s Arthur Round Table. All
of them are quarreling with their neighbors. How many ways can King
Arthur choose five knights such that no two of them are quarreling?

Could someone explain how to solve this problem, the given solution is very systematic/rigorous/unhelpful. I tried saying "If we start with 1, then the distinct cases are choosing two away from one(blocking one option) or three away from one(blocking two options)" and proceeding from there but not only is it arduous, it is not correct. I also tried to instead solve "How many ways can Arthur arrange 5 knights(who are not sat down yet) that always quarrel with each other, at least two seats apart?", which was really promising but overcounts and I now believe is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I have counted 36. You can consider choosing these knights: (1,3,5,7,9), (1,3,5,7,10) or (1,3,5,8,10). Each one of these choices could be rotated 12 times.

Comment: @Bio Its right, could you write this as an answer with a little more explanation

Comment: You might get some ideas from this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3480221/choosing-non-adjacent-chairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the 5 chosen knights seated around a table. To keep them apart we add 5 empty chairs :
K * K * K * K * K *

We have 2 chairs remaining. Remembering that the line bends round into a circle, we can add the 2 chairs to create 3 distinct circular patterns :
K * K * K * K * K * * *  (5-0)
K * K * K * K * * K * *  (4-1)
K * K * K * * K * K * *  (3-2)

Each of these 3 patterns can be rotated around the circular table in 12 positions. So the total number of combinations of knights is 36.

Check by enumeration. Number the knights 1-12. List the allowed combinations of knights in order :

1-3-5-7-9
1-3-5-7-10
1-3-5-7-11
1-3-5-8-10
1-3-5-8-11
1-3-5-9-11
1-3-6-8-10
1-3-6-8-11
1-3-6-9-11
1-3-7-9-11
1-4-6-8-10
1-4-6-8-11
1-4-6-9-11
1-4-7-9-11
1-5-7-9-11
(15)
2-4-6-8-10
2-4-6-8-11
2-4-6-8-12
2-4-6-9-11
2-4-6-9-12
2-4-6-10-12
2-4-7-9-11
2-4-7-9-12
2-4-7-10-12
2-4-8-10-12
2-5-7-9-11
2-5-7-9-12
2-5-7-10-12
2-5-8-10-12
2-6-8-10-12
(15)
3-5-7-9-11
3-5-7-9-12
3-5-7-10-12
3-5-8-10-12
3-6-8-10-12
(5)
4-6-8-10-12
(1)